# How to disable two-fingers/right-click in touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

I would like to disable the function right-click when tapping the touchpad with two fingers, because it is always interfering with the two-fingers/scrolling function. I also would like to maintain the function left-click when double tapping with one finger.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you comfortable with the command prompt?

You can configure in detail how you want your touchpad to behave using `synclient`

You can get a list of current settings by doing `synclient -l`

For your specific request, you will need to run `synclient TapButton2=0` to dissable the feature. To make the feature persistent create a ~/touchpad.sh configuration.

[More info...](http://www.howtogeek.com/118817/how-to-swap-the-two-and-three-finger-touchpad-tap-actions-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Mark question as answered then? Cheers.

Comment: Thank you! occasional righclicks while scrolling with two finger bothered me for a long time.

Comment: Why isn'ter there a /etc/synclient.d/  like every other program?

Answer (score 5):

To summarize most everything that everyone has said, just open a console and run the following three commands:

```
echo "synclient TapButton2=0" > ~/.touchpad.sh
chmod +x ~/.touchpad.sh
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.input-devices hotplug-command “~/.touchpad.sh”
```

Comment: This worked until I logged out. I suppose the hotplug command wasn't working for some reason.