# two finger scrolling causing a right click (ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: 15.04, touchpad, synaptics

When I use two finger scrolling, and then remove my fingers from the touchpad, it is causing a right click at the end.

For example, I'll be scrolling down a wikipedia page.  As soon as I am done scrolling, the right click menu opens up.  It is so frustrating.  Any way to stop this?

***EDIT:***

I've already set `TapButton2=0`, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Output of `$ xinput --list-props "DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN"`:

```
xinput --list-props "DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN"
Device 'DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (270): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (271):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (272):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (273):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (294):  48, 1168, 36, 644
    Synaptics Finger (295): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (296):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (297):   61
    Synaptics Tap Durations (298):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (299):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (300):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (301):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (302):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (303): -27, -27
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (304): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (305):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (306): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.143575, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (307):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (308):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (309):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (310): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (311):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (312): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (313):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (314): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (315):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (316): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (317):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (318): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (319):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (320): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (321):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (322):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (323):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (324):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (325): 12, 12
    Synaptics Area (326):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (327):  608, 0, 557, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (328): 6, 6
    Device Product ID (257):    1739, 30381
    Device Node (258):  "/dev/input/event7"
```

Comment: Please restate your question with the name maker and model of your laptop.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer below (to be expanded), output of `$ xinput --list` would be handy. So would be the content of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` which are the configuration settings loaded at boot time. You can put those outputs in paste.ubuntu.com and paste the corresponding url in yr post by editing it. It makes yr question more readable for others. (Scroll is generally a bad idea!) -- to get back to me or anyone on AU , insert @<username> in yr answer or comment like so: @Cbhihe.

Comment: BTW, are you using a DELL XPS series laptop ?

Comment: And please tell us if you have a touch screen .

Comment: I see neither answers to my questions nor any new edit of your original question with new requested content ... :-|   But since yr question is marked as duplicate, try to reword it or to explain why you could think it is not a dup of @gg-79's similar sounding question. Then either ask for cancellation of the duplicate status by posting a comment addressed to Mitch (for that use the address @Mitch), or move on an ask a new different sounding question. In any case yr prbm looks tractable, so there's hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your touch-pad device is confused between your Two Finger Drag action and the also valid Two Finger Tap action. You need to modify your configuration file for the touchpad, but first determine what device is installed. Check which touchpad driver you have.

From the terminal (to get a terminal window, do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+T):

```
$ xinput --list
```

to list yr Xorg session input devices (kbd+mouse+touchpad+etc.). You should get something like this, e.g. for the "SynPS/2 Synaptics" driver:

```
Virtual core pointer                  id=2  [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer      id=4  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse               id=10 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad      id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse              id=13 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard               id=3  [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard     id=5  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                    id=6  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                       id=7  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                    id=8  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ...
```

IDs will be different and listed devices too (as yr box is likely different from mine and I run Ubuntu 14.04.3).

Check that you have a pointing device with "TouchPad" in its name (id=12 in my case). In terminal type, replacing `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` with the fullname of yr touchpad device, as shown below:

```
$ xinput --list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

---

Spoiler: In terminal you may issue:

```
$ synclient -l 
$ synclient TapButton2=0
$ synclient -l | grep TapButton2
```

to list set properties of yr TouchPad device and to disable yr two Finger Tap action in the case of the "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" driver.

To make that disabling permanent, you can easily adapt a solution from [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/118817/how-to-swap-the-two-and-three-finger-touchpad-tap-actions-on-ubuntu/) or from (I just discovered it now on AU) @captainskyhawk's summary in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299117/how-to-disable-two-fingers-right-click-in-touchpad).

---

***From your EDIT:***

I am not certain of that but there could be a threshold setting issue with either the "Synaptics Finger" property. From [www.x.org](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html):

- *Option "FingerLow" "integer"  ( Property: "Synaptics Finger" ) ---
  When finger pressure drops below this value, the driver counts it as a release.*
- *Option "FingerHigh" "integer"  ( Property: "Synaptics Finger" ) ---
  When finger pressure goes above this value, the driver counts it as a touch.*
- *Option "FingerPress" "integer" ( Property: "Synaptics Finger" ) ---
  When finger pressure goes above this value, the driver counts it as a press. Currently a press is equivalent to putting the touchpad in trackstick emulation mode.*

The latter is set to 0.